# Cannot use "@" character in C# cdn link to stylesheet

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, stylesheet, cdn

I'm trying to use this link inside a line of code in my cshtml file in order to access the mdi stylesheet: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css".

For some reason, my program is taking issue with the '@' character before the mdi; it is hilighting it in yellow. When I try to run the code, I get this message:

error CS0103: The name 'mdi' does not exist in the current context

Interestingly, the other '@' in the string does not cause any issues. 
Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` has special meaning in cshtml pages. You need to escape it using either `&#64;` or `%40`

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/&#64;mdi/font&#64;4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css`

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/%40mdi/font%404.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css`

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved it. Really appreciate it!

Comment: so happy to help

Comment: Both of these fail to work when fetching the file